# ldd started to show me “not a dynamic executable”

Tags: libraries, executable

I am a bit confused because I don't understand why it happens:
The last changes on the system that I remember were

- installed g++5 for the old porject (removed already)
- apt autoclean
- [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758828/purging-and-rebuilding-ldconfig-cache) ldconfig cache (guess this is the reason)

Now I can't launch some of the applications. Ldd tells me that it's “not a dynamic executable”

```
igor@Linbox:/lib/i386-linux-gnu$ ldd libssl.so.1.0.0 
    is not a dynamic executable

igor@Linbox:/lib/i386-linux-gnu$ ldd libselinux.so.1 
    is not a dynamic executable

igor@Linbox:/bin$ ldd dd 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff0b380000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb618c76000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb619269000)           

igor@Linbox:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ldd libc.so.6 
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcb44373000)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffed8f33000)
```

Version: Linux Linbox 4.13.0-46-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 12 12:36:29 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Also I checked that it is still present:

```
// for running x32 applications on x64 system
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Since removed `ld.so.cache` I did `sudo ldconfig`. There is new cache in `/etc/ld.so.cache`

Do I miss some library?

Added file checks:

```
file /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=c1e3854cb8b86f1006dc391d23f102ea1184cf25, stripped
file /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=396cda857e41036061599a59c9f5fe62d7b50c4d, stripped
dpkg -S /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
libssl1.0.0:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
dpkg -S /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
libselinux1:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
```

Checked libx32 from comments:

```
igor@Linbox:/lib/i386-linux-gnu$ ls -l /libx32/ld*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 155092 Jan 12  2018 /libx32/ld-2.26.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     10 Jan 12  2018 /libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2 -> ld-2.26.so
```

Comment: You can check filetype with `file /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0` and `file /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1`. Also check their package names with `dpkg -S /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0` and `dpkg -S /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1`. Please add all this output to the question.

Comment: I wonder if `ld-linux-x32.so` is missing or broken? what is the output of `ls -l /libx32/ld*`?

Comment: ls -l /libx32/ld* --> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root /libx32/ld-2.26.so, lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      /libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2 --> ld-2.26.so; ldd ld-2.26.so -> is not a dynamic executable;

Comment: Your 4.13 kernel (16.04.4) reached EOL Aug 2018.  Try upgrading your HWE stack to the next release.

Comment: The usual location for the 32 bit loader is /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so.  ldd checks /libx32, but that directory does not even exist on my 18.04 system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem (thx to ubfan1) by updating kernel from `4.13.0-46-generic` up to `4.15.0-39-generic`:

```
$ uname -a
Linux Linbox 4.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 23 15:48:01 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

/lib/i386-linux-gnu$ ldd libselinux.so.1 
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7fca000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xf7ee6000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7ee1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7d05000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7fcc000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7ce6000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bug 1616609, ldd reports incorrectly "not a dynamic executable" when the executable's loader is not present , is probably the cause of the problem (as steeldriver suggested).  Reinstall the libc6-x32 package to get it back.  Do consider adding yourself to the bug, maybe it'll be fixed one day -- a patch is even suggested.

Comment: I did sudo apt remove libc6-x32 and then sudo apt install libc6-x32; Still the same.

Answer (score 1):

So this worked for me.  ldd is a script. Near the top (line 29 on my arm Debian 10) it bases all the library searching on RTLDLIST=/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1. After installing arm 32 bit libraries (dpkg --add-architecture armhf; apt update; etc), I took a look in /lib and saw ld-linux-armhf.so.3 right next to ld-linux-aarch64.so.1.  So then this stopped ldd saying "not a dynamic executable":

1. copy /usr/bin/ldd to /usr/bin/ldd32
2. edit /usr/bin/ldd32
3. replace RTLDLIST=/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 with RTLDLIST=/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
4. ldd32 <32 bit binary>

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that your glibc executables come from a wrong
glibc version. Your system behaves as 32-bit if the last glibc is 32-bit.
So if you want 64-bit system with 32-bit support, after installing 32-bit libraries, you must reinstall 64-bit
glibc.