# error while loading shared libraries: libm.so.6: cannot stat shared object: Error 38

Tags: shared-library

I am a Linux noob trying to compile a 32 bit program and run it on 64bit Ubuntu.  It compiles fine but when I run it I get this error:
error while loading shared libraries: libm.so.6: cannot stat shared object: Error 38

I have searched for libm.so.6 and found it in /lib32 and /libx32.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you compile the program? what is the result of `ldd prog` (where `prog` is replaced by the name of the compiled executable program)?

Comment: ldd cr2hdr gives "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: I have tried compiling a simple "Hello,  world" program.  I used this to compile: gcc -m32 hello.c ;  When I run ldd a.out I get this result: "not a dynamic executable".  If I remove the "-m32" option it works.  I am trying to compile a much more complex program to 32bit binary and have reduced the problem to the most simple example.  The program requires a 32bit binary.

Comment: Actually the binary hello.c needs is libc.so.6 but it is basically the same problem.

Comment: Is the `gcc-multilib` package (and its dependencies) installed?

Comment: I just ran "sudo apt install gcc-multilib" and "sudo ldconfig" (I assumed this was needed).  I recompiled,  for fun.  I have the same problem

Comment: Well if you are still getting *"not a dynamic executable"* when you try to run `ldd` on the binary, it suggests the 32-bit loader is missing - see for example [ldd started to show me “not a dynamic executable”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097900/ldd-started-to-show-me-not-a-dynamic-executable) and perhaps [edit] your question to include the output of `ls -l /libx32/ld-*`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason but no solution.
The reason is that the environment I am using has no 32bit support in the kernel.
The environment is UserLAnd running on Android.
The developers confirmed there is no 32bit support.

Thanks to everyone for the help.